push reload or invoke javascript function from server
I have Django + React + uwsgi application.
Uwsgi access to the database.
Now I want to reload Django(React) web applicataion triggered by Database is changed.
For example

User open the web application
Administrator use mysql command on server Insert into mytable(name) values("data")
User's application will be reloaded or some javascript function be called.

It's something like push reload from server.
In my idea. Web application access the database to check the value is altered in every seconds.
However It requires to access API every seconds.
(And at most it has the one seconds delay, or requires too much api access)
Is this a good practice ?
Is there any good method for this purpose??

Modern solution generally uses websockets to establish a communication channel from server to client and the server can then inform the client to reload whatever necessary - aka hot-reloading. This thread relates to using websockets with django to issue live updates, or a way to do hot reloading in general in django. Having clients polling once a second for updates can result in significant server load.

Thank you for your advice!! I am researching about  websocket, and found the way to integrate websocket and django.
